# How to return a list field in FastAPI?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I'm using a model like:

```
class Question(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str = Field(..., min_length=3, max_length=50)
    answer_true: str = Field(..., min_length=3, max_length=50)
    answer_false: list
    category_id: int
```

And trying to get the `questions` using the following function:

```
def get(id: int):
    query = questions.select().where(id == questions.c.id)
    return database.fetch_one(query=query)

@router.get("/{id}/", response_model=Question)
def read_question(id: int = Path(..., gt=0),):
    question = get(id)
    if not question:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="question not found")
    return question
```

And here is the data that has been stored in the database:

[image]

But it can't return the `list` field (`answer_false`) correctly and this field's values are being returned as characters:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because of my sqlalchemy config. I Removed `dimensions` in the table's config it the problem got fixed:

```
questions = Table(
    "questions",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("title", String(50)),
    Column("answer_true", String(50)),
    Column("answer_false", ARRAY(String)), ## adding dimension will cause the list to not work in get requests
    Column("created_date", DateTime, default=func.now(), nullable=False),
    Column("category_id", Integer, ForeignKey("categories.id")),
)
```